# Any way to view rejected edit source?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, markdown, rejected-edits

Is there any way to view rejected edit source?

I have recently suggested an edit which was rejected. All three reviewers decided it better be a comment or an answer. **So, how does one find rejected edit source in order to not type everything from scratch especially formatting, citations and links?**

Fortunately after seeing first reject I navigated to mine-edited answer, which still displayed my edits, allowing me via `edit` link obtain source code of my edit.

Now that my edit was rejected it is impossible to obtain its source from any UI. "Suggested Edits" view has only "rendered output" and "markdown" selectors. Although I must admit, markdown diff is good as last resort, it is not good enough. To be more specific, it does not allow easy copying as selection originally started at suggested edit tends to eventually grab original paragraphs if diff is complex.

Searching the Meta similar question was found:
[Add a view to see the raw source of suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90739/152659)
Alas the answer there does not provide any hint on obtaining the source of suggested edit. Thus the answer there could be satisfactory for the problem raised there, but cannot address the issue in this question, so it is not a duplicate.

In the end, if this is not implemented yet, I'm asking to implement `a view to see the raw source of suggested edits`.

Comment: How is the "raw source" different from the "markdown" view?

Comment: @Floern Raw source is readily copiable. "Markdown" diff is not copy-friendly.

Comment: @PF4Public The right-hand side of the diff is very close to the original source of the rejected edit. You'll have to remove the struck-out parts in red, but that's it.

Comment: @DanBron The problem with markdown diff is that selection started at the beginning of suggested edit will eventually grab also original paragraphs. Try yourself :)

Comment: @PF4Public Oh, you're right! Both your comments here are worthwhile adding to the body of your question.  Also a  link to an example rejected edit, so people can easily experiment for themselves, would be useful.

Comment: @DanBron Quite reasonable, thanks. Question edited. With respect to providing example rejected edit I feel reluctant to provide mine so as not to trigger discussion on that particular reject. Having only 1 I have no much choice here :(

Comment: Here, use [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6149041), it's not mine, but it was made on one of my posts, and I actually think it's quite reasonable. It got rejected before I had a chance to review it, and I've been too lazy to incorporate its good ideas back into my answer. Unfortunately it doesn't really highlight the "copy/paste captures material from left-hand-side too" problem, which I think is the crux of your question here, and separates it from previous questions.

Comment: @DanBron Since comments are right beneath the question, anyone reading them can see your example as it is, so +1 for your example. Besides, I think that most people have at least 1 reject to experiment with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is using SEDE for this. Note that SEDE is updated once a week, so the data might still not be there, but in case it is, the below might be helpful. To see when SEDE was last updated, you can  run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/668129/see-when-sede-was-last-updated).

1. Obtain the suggested edit ID from the URL, e.g.:

   > [image]
2. Go to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/668128/get-raw-text-of-a-suggested-edit)
3. Switch sites to the desired site where the edit was rejected, e.g.

   > [image]
4. **Tick the "Text-only results" checkbox** and put the ID of the suggested edit in the SuggestedEditId textbox:

   > [image]
5. Click "Run Query"

That is it, the source of the edit suggestion is right there ready to be copied:

> [image]

Comment: Fascinating approach! So if it is acceptable to wait for a SEDE update, then this is definitely the answer. Otherwise the other answer is also handy!

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to run this in the browser console (switch to the markdown view first), then copy what's left:

```
$("table.full-diff tr td.content:nth-child(1)").remove()
```

This removes the entire left pane of the diff, leaving only the original content, minus deletions and plus your additions.

In cases where there are "(n) identical lines skipped", you'll have to pull the unchanged lines from the markdown source on the previous revision.

Comment: Kind of hacky, but does the job done until they change the layout. Also could be cumbersome if many identical lines present. Since there's no reply from the developers, this is the best solution, thus marking accepted.